# set of nilpotent in $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Let $N=N(\mathbb Z_n)$ be the set of all nilpotent elements in $\mathbb Z_n$. How do I prove that $N$ is closed under addition and that it is an abelian group with respect to addition?

I started off saying that its closed under addition if $x,y\in\mathbb Z_n$ (where $kx=0, ky=0$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$) and $x+y\in\mathbb Z_n$.

Is this correct? or do I have to show for $x^k=0,y^k=0$ and $(x+y)^k=0$? 
If this is the case how do I do that... I'm very stuck...

Comment: Usually, a *nilpotent element* is with respect to the product, so you need to prove that $x^k=0$ and $y^n=0$, then there is $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $(x+y)^m=0$ (notice that $k,n$ and $m$ need not be equal, so it may not be $x^k=y^k=0$)

Comment: @Alessandro: $n$ is already used for $\mathbf Z_n$. It can't be used for the nilpotence index.

Comment: @Bernard You're right, it might be confusing too

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x^a=y^b=0$, for $a,b\in\mathbb N$, you need to find $m$ such that $(x+y)^m=0$

**Hint:** Use the binomial theorem $$(x+y)^m=\sum^m_{j=0}\binom{m}{j}x^jy^{m-j}$$ since $x^a=0$, then $x^{a'}=0$ for every $a'\geqslant a$, and similarly $y^{b'}=0$ for every $b'\geqslant b$. Can you find a $m$ such  that $x^jy^{m-j}$ is $=0$ for every $0\leqslant j\leqslant m$?

**Solution:** Look for $m$ such that for every $0\leqslant j\leqslant m$, either $j\geqslant a$ or $m-j\geqslant b$. One such $m$ can be $a+b$